# How to optimise this Langton's ant sim?

Tags: c, optimization

I'm writing a Langton's ant sim (for rulestring RLR) and am trying to optimise it for speed. Here's the pertinent code as it stands:

```
#define AREA_X 65536
#define AREA_Y 65536
#define TURN_LEFT 3
#define TURN_RIGHT 1
int main()
{
  uint_fast8_t* state;
  uint_fast64_t ant=((AREA_Y/2)*AREA_X) + (AREA_X/2);
  uint_fast8_t ant_orientation=0;
  uint_fast8_t two_pow_five=32;
  uint32_t two_pow_thirty_two=0;/*not fast, relying on exact width for overflow*/
  uint_fast8_t change_orientation[4]={0, TURN_RIGHT, TURN_LEFT, TURN_RIGHT};
  int_fast64_t* move_ant={AREA_X, 1, -AREA_X, -1};
  ... initialise empty state
  while(1)
  {
    while(two_pow_five--)/*removing this by doing 32 steps per inner loop, ~16% longer*/
    {
      while(--two_pow_thirty_two)
      {
        /*one iteration*/
        /* 54 seconds for init + 2^32 steps
        ant_orientation = ( ant_orientation + (117>>((++state[ant])*2 )) )&3;
        state[ant] = (36 >> (state[ant] *2) ) & 3;
        ant+=move_ant[ant_orientation];
        */

        /* 47 seconds for init + 2^32 steps
        ant_orientation = ( ant_orientation + ((state[ant])==1?3:1) )&3;
        state[ant] += (state[ant]==2)?-2:1;
        ant+=move_ant[ant_orientation];
        */

        /* 46 seconds for init + 2^32 steps
        ant_orientation = ( ant_orientation + ((state[ant])==1?3:1) )&3;
        if(state[ant]==2)
        {
          --state[ant];
          --state[ant];
        }
        else
          ++state[ant];
        ant+=move_ant[ant_orientation];
        */

        /* 44 seconds for init + 2^32 steps
        ant_orientation = ( ant_orientation + ((++state[ant])==2?3:1) )&3;
        if(state[ant]==3)state[ant]=0;
        ant+=move_ant[ant_orientation];
        */

        // 37 seconds for init + 2^32 steps
        // handle every situation with nested switches and constants
        switch(ant_orientation)
        {
          case 0:
            switch(state[ant])
            {
              case 0:
                ant_orientation=1;
                state[ant]=1;
                ++ant;
                break;
              case 1:
                ant_orientation=3;
                state[ant]=2;
                --ant;
                break;
              case 2:
                ant_orientation=1;
                state[ant]=0;
                ++ant;
                break;
            }
            break;
          case 1:
            switch(state[ant])
            {
              ...
            }
            break;
          case 2:
            switch(state[ant])
            {
              ...
            }
            break;
          case 3:
            switch(state[ant])
            {
              ...
            }
            break;
        }

      }
    }
    two_pow_five=32;
    ... dump to file every 2^37 steps
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I have two questions:

1. I've tried to optimise as best as I can with c by trial and error testing, are there any tricks I haven't taken advantage of? Please try to talk in c not assembly, although I'll probably try assembly at some point.
2. Is there a better way to model the problem to increase speed?

More info: Portability doesn't matter. I'm on 64 bit linux, using gcc, an i5-2500k and 16 GB of ram. The state array as it stands uses 4GiB, the program could feasibly use 12GiB of ram. sizeof(uint_fast8_t)=1. Bounds checks are intentionally not present, corruption is easy to spot manually from the dumps.

**edit:** Perhaps counter-inuitively, piling on the switch statements instead of eliminating them has yielded the best efficiency so far.

**edit:** I've re-modelled the problem and come up with something quicker than a single step per iteration. Before, each state element used two bits and described a single cell in the Langton's ant grid. The new way uses all 8 bits, and describes a 2x2 section of the grid. Every iteration a variable number of steps are done, by looking up pre-computed values of step count, new orientation and new state for the current state+orientation. Assuming everything is equally likely it averages to 2 steps taken per iteration. As a bonus it uses 1/4 of the memory to model the same area:

```
while(--iteration)
{
        // roughly 31 seconds per 2^32 steps
        table_offset=(state[ant]*24)+(ant_orientation*3);
        it+=twoxtwo_table[table_offset+0];
        state[ant]=twoxtwo_table[table_offset+2];
        ant+=move_ant2x2[(ant_orientation=twoxtwo_table[table_offset+1])];
}
```

Haven't tried optimising it yet, the next thing to try is eliminating the offset equation and lookups with nested switches and constants like before (but with 648 inner cases instead of 12).

Comment: Your double-case opt. seems to be ultimate :D

Answer (score 3):

Or, you can use a single **unsigned byte constant** as an artificial register instead of branching:

```
value:   1  3  1  1
bits:   01 11 01 01 ---->101 decimal value for an unsigned byte
index    3  2  1  0  ---> get first 2 bits to get  "1"  (no shift)
                      --> get second 2 bits to get "1"  (shifting for 2 times)
                      --> get third 2 bits to get  "3"  (shifting for 4 times)
                      --> get last 2 bits to get   "1"  (shifting for 6 times)

 Then "AND" the result with  binary(11) or decimal(3) to get your value.

 (101>>( (++state[ant])*2  ) ) & 3 would give you the turnright or turnleft

 Example:
 ++state[ant]= 0:  ( 101>>( (0)*2 ) )&3  --> 101 & 3 = 1
 ++state[ant]= 1:  ( 101>>( (1)*2 ) )&3  --> 101>>2 & 3 = 1
 ++state[ant]= 2:  ( 101>>( (2)*2 ) )&3  --> 101>>4 & 3 = 3  -->turn left
 ++state[ant]= 3:  ( 101>>( (3)*2 ) )&3  --> 101>>6 & 3 = 1

 Maximum six-shifting + one-multiplication + one-"and" may be better.
 Dont forget constant can be auto-promoted so you may add some suffixes or something else.
```

**Since you are using "unsigned int" for the %4 modulus, you can use "and" operation.**

```
  state[ant]=state[ant]&3; instead of state[ant]=state[ant]%4;
```

For unskilled compilers, this should increase speed.

**The hardest part: modulo-3**

```
  C = A % B is equivalent to C = A – B * (A / B)
  We need  state[ant]%3
  Result = state[ant] - 3 * (state[ant]/3)

  state[ant]/3 is always <=1 for your valid direction states.
  Only when state[ant]  is 3 then state[ant]/3 is 1, other values give 0.
  When multiplied by 3, that part is 0 or 3 (only 3 when state[ant] is 3 otherwise 0)
  Result = state[ant] - (0 or 3)

  Lets look at all possibilities:

  state[ant]=0:  0 - 0  ---> 0   ----> 00100100 shifted by 0 times &3 --> 00000000
  state[ant]=1:  1 - 0  ---> 1   ----> 00100100 shifted by 2 times &3 --> 00000001
  state[ant]=2:  2 - 0  ---> 2   ----> 00100100 shifted by 4 times &3 --> 00000010
  state[ant]=3:  3 - 3  ---> 0   ----> 00100100 shifted by 6 times &3 --> 00000000

  00100100 is 36 in decimal.

  (36 >> (state[ant] *2) ) & 3 will give you state[ant]%3 for your valid states (0,1,2,3)

  Example: 

  state[ant]=0: 36 >> 0  --> 36 ----> 36& 3 ----> 0  satisfies 0%3
  state[ant]=1: 36 >> 2  --> 9 -----> 9 & 3 ----> 1  satisfies 1%3
  state[ant]=2: 36 >> 4  --> 2 -----> 2 & 3 ----> 2 satisfies  2%3
  state[ant]=3: 36 >> 6  --> 0 -----> 0 & 3 ----> 0 satisfies 3%3
```

Comment: Thank you, this sped it up by ~11%. &3 did it in 14 instructions, 8 less than %4.

Comment: Tried removing branch already, see change_orientation array and the comment above the ant_orientation line. Much slower for some reason. Would it be quicker than a branch if it could somehow be kept in the cpu cache, if so how to do it?

Comment: Now finally done with the third &3 bit twiddling optimization. Each optimization should give about %11 to a sum of %33 boost. Have fun!

Comment: I'll look at intrinsics tomorrow. The  (117>>((++state[ant])*2)) is slower even when the &3 is omitted (which we can, as that added to the previous orientation is about to be &3). It might be because of promotion, this says arithmetic operators do not accept types smaller than int as arguments: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast

(36 >> (state[ant] *2) ) & 3 takes roughly the same time as %3. An if statement is actually ~6% quicker than both: if(state[ant]==3)state[ant]=0;

Thank you for the good feedback. This is fun, I'll have another play tomorrow ;)

Comment: It's not possible to update states in parallel. Each iteration relies on the previous as it determines where the ant is, aka which state element is next. It might be possible to handle a small number of iterations at once and do some magic that way, seems unlikely though.